# regex how to match mutiple pattern

Tags: regex

what pattern should i use in regex if i want to match the first pattern but then i want to unmatch the second pattern.

for example i want to match the string 'id' followed by decimal as long as that decimal is not 6 or 9.

so it should match `id1,id2,id3 ...` etc but not `id6` and `id9`.

I tried this pattern and it's not working :

```
"id(\d|(?!6|9))"
```

Comment: You have to write all numbers into a characters class except `6` and `9`. Something like this: [`/id[12345780]/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/uI8uZ7/2)

Comment: Is this (`id1`..`id9`) a good example of what you actually want to achieve, or have you oversimplified your problem? I only ask because such a small range of possible things to check against doesn't sound like a real-world situation.

Comment: Please clarify if `id` will be followed by multiple digits or not ?

Comment: I added details on why your regex does not work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `negative lookahead` like this.

**Regex:** `\bid(?![69])\d\b`

**Explanation:**

- `\b` ensures the word boundary.
- `(?![69])` negative lookahead makes sure that number is not 6 or 9.
- `\d` matches a single digit after `id`.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aN2uN7/3)**

Comment: You have to write `+` after `\d` in your pattern, to matches `id89`.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: That would equal my answer.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: Since OP used `\d` in his attempt I assumed it would only single digit.Let me clarify if OP want to match multiple digits. Otherwise just because I assume **multiple digits** people will be quick on down vote button.

Comment: @noob I understand  .. The question is kinda vague .. Anyway for this kind of questions you can write two patterns for both jobs separately.

Comment: Yes I was writing that when Wiktor came up with alternative solution so there was not point in repeating same stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Its not the best solution but you can also do this using `positive look ahead` as

```
\bid(?=\d)(?:\d\d+|[^69])\b
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
\b #word boundary
  id  #Match id literally
  (?=\d) #Find if the next position contains digit (otherwise fails)
  (?:  #Non capturing group
     \d\d+  #If there are more than one digits then match is success
       |    #OR (alternation)
     [^69]  #If its single digit don't match 6 or 9
  )   #End of non capturing group
\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI8uZ7/4)**

If you want to check `id` is not followed by `6` or `9` and you want to accept cases like `id16` but not `id61`, then you can use

```
\bid(?=\d)[^69]\d*\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI8uZ7/5)**

Comment: Your pattern matches `id69` which `id` is fallowing by `6`.

Comment: @Shafizadeh the OP didn't mention that it should not match anything containing `6` or `9`

Comment: Not containing ... following. I think OP wants to match `id16`, but not `id61`

Comment: @Shafizadeh `\bid(?=\d)[^69]\d*\b`.. is this ok??
https://regex101.com/r/uI8uZ7/5

Comment: Yes it is `:-)` ... +1

Answer (score 1):

The `id(\d|(?!6|9))` pattern matches `id` followed with any 1 digit or if there is no `6` or `9`. That *alternation* (`\d` or `(?!6|9)`) allows `id6` and `id9` because the first alternative "wins" in NFA regex (i.e. the further alternatives after one matches are not tested against).

If you need to only exclude `id` matches  with `6` or `9` use

```
\bid(?![69]\b)\d+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI6oS8/1)

If you want to avoid matching all `id` with `6` and `9` following it, use

```
\bid(?![69])\d+
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lI6oS8/2).

Here, `\d+` matches *one or more digits*, `\b` stands for a word boundary (the digits should be preceded and followed with non-"word" characters),  and the `(?![69])` lookahead fails the match if there is `6` or `9` after `id` (with or without a word boundary check - depending on what you need).

**UPDATE**

If you need to exclude the `id` whose number does not start with `6` or `9`, you can use

```
\bid[0-578]\d*
```

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zP8mP2/1))

Based on [Shafizadeh's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398928/regex-how-to-match-mutiple-pattern/36399072?noredirect=1#comment60415097_36399072) comment.

Comment: By the way *negative lookahead* is fine in this case, but still I think using a *character class* would be much faster than *lookahead*. https://regex101.com/r/lI6oS8/3

Comment: @Shafizadeh: This approach cannot be used to check if the number is not equal to `6` or `9`. It can only be used if you want to check if the number does not *start with* `6` or `9`.